# What is the norm and how do you calculate it in this case?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I am reading the following proof that 5 is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$:

> Suppose that $5\mid (a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})$ for $a+b\sqrt{2},c+d\sqrt{2}$. By taking the norm, we obtain $25\mid (a^2-2b^2)(c^2-2d^2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

My question is, what exactly is a norm and how is it calculated?

Comment: Please don't put vital parts of you question in offsite links.  You can edit your post to include the text of the book that you are working out of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, then the norm of $\alpha$ is $$N(\alpha)=(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=a^2 - 2b^2$$

The norm $N$ is just a useful function $$N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$that has some nice properties:

- $N(\alpha)=1\iff\alpha$ is a unit
- $N(\alpha)N(\beta)=N(\alpha\beta)$

Comment: Why is this beeing down voted?